# Converterlogic, bind property too many elements (radio buttons)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I started to use a converterlogic to control the visual output of my GUI based on propertys of my model, which gets populated from SQL. It seems too produce a lot of overhead and code, so I am not sure if I implement the technology the right way.

Here's a snapshot:

[image]

The radio buttons disable / enable some controls, that is so, because the propertys are bound more than once and are to interprete differently, based on the selected mode.

The so called mode is a string property in my model "Selectionmode", filled with one of three values (quarter, month, week).

For each of the three radio buttons I created a valueconverter which looks like the following:

```
class IsQuarterModeConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                if (value.ToString() == "Quarter")
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return ((bool)value) ? "Quarter" : Binding.DoNothing;
        }
    }
```

This is my radio button XAML:

```
<RadioButton x:Name="G_rb_quarter" Content="Aktiv" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="rbg_auswertungszeitraum" 
                                         IsChecked="{Binding MySelectedItem.Selectionmode, Converter={StaticResource IsQuarterModeConverter}}" />
```

This actually works and always save the right value into my model, which can be persisted into the database for later usage.
But for real, a class with two functions for each possible value and element? I can't believe I am doing this the right way.

Any advice on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (at least) two alternatives.

**First**, if you want to use a Converter then you could have a rather generic one which uses the `ConverterParameter` from the binding and looks something like this:

```
public class SelectionModeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value?.ToString() == parameter.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool)value ? parameter.ToString() : Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

Your radio button can now define the `Selectionmode` that should enable the selection:

```
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding MySelectedItem.Selectionmode,
    Converter={StaticResource SelectionModeConverter}, ConverterParameter=Quarter}" />
```

The other radio buttons would get `ConverterParameter=Month` and `ConverterParameter=Week` respectively.

**Or second**, you could place the logic in your view model which could look something like this:

```
public class SelectionViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _selectionmode = null;

    public string Selectionmode
    {
        get { return _selectionmode; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectionmode == value)
                return;

            _selectionmode = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsQuarterSelected));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsMonthSelected));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsWeekSelected));
        }
    }

    public bool IsQuarterSelected
    {
        get { return Selectionmode == "Quarter"; }
        set { Selectionmode = value ? "Quarter" : Selectionmode; }
    }

    public bool IsMonthSelected
    {
        get { return Selectionmode == "Month"; }
        set { Selectionmode = value ? "Month" : Selectionmode; }
    }

    public bool IsWeekSelected
    {
        get { return Selectionmode == "Week"; }
        set { Selectionmode = value ? "Week" : Selectionmode; }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

The radio buttons would then just use these properties:

```
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding MySelectedItem.IsQuarterSelected}" />
```

I can't say which one of the two possible ways is the better one in your case because that really depends on your application architecture and how you've implemented your MVVM framework.

In my case I would probably use the properties in the view model because I don't like to use many converters when I'm using MVVM.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the very detailed answer and you even pointed out an additional way to solve this. I guess I will rework my converterlogic to a more generic way with converterparameters - I guess this is what I actually searched for.

Comment: @kurdy Glad I could help you!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

You won't need a converter per value if use converterParameter:

```
public class SelectionModeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            if (value.ToString() == (string)parameter)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((bool)value) ? parameter : Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

and also add ConverterParameter to binding:

```
IsChecked="{Binding MySelectedItem.Selectionmode, 
                    ConverterParameter='Quater',
                    Converter={StaticResource IsQuarterModeConverter}}"
```

Comment: The other answer is a lot more detailed, so I marked it as answer for future readers, but I honored you for mentioning the same solution (: